# ImageShack is showing "Unregistered domain. Go to http://imageshack.us to register" instead of my pictures

Tags: imageshack

Instead of showing the images I've uploaded, ImageShack has started showing the generic frog image with the following message:

> Unregistered domain. Go to http://imageshack.us to register.

[image: frog stuck inside ice cube]

Why is this coming up?

Comment: @msh210 ever run into this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ImageShack has apparently changed their policies and [now insist upon registering the referring domain onto ImageShack](http://stream.imageshack.us/content.php?page=register_domain) . If the domain is not registered with an ImageShack account then the images will not be shown and the above picture will be substituted.

However, if the end user is a registered ImageShack user, then they will show the image.

Answer (score 2):

Same here. Here's the solution:

http://www.brymayor.com/2011/02/imageshack-image-issue-picture-not-showing-frog-image/

However I tried to register my domain but they haven't verified my domain yet. As of now, I've been trying to relocate all the images to other host.